# Order By and Aliases (As)

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join, distinct, aliases

I was solving this [PostreSQL excercise](https://pgexercises.com/questions/joins/threejoin.html) (in the link you can find the statement and the database diagram) and I came out with this solution:

```
SELECT mem.firstname || ' ' || mem.surname AS member, fac.name AS facility
FROM 
    cd.members mem
    INNER JOIN cd.bookings book
        ON mem.memid = book.memid
    INNER JOIN cd.facilities fac
        ON book.facid = fac.facid
WHERE
    fac.facid IN (0,1)
ORDER BY mem.firstname, fac.name
```

Which actually didn't work because I would still get duplicates, so I decided to check out the provided solution:

```
select distinct mems.firstname || ' ' || mems.surname as member, facs.name as facility
from 
    cd.members mems
    inner join cd.bookings bks
        on mems.memid = bks.memid
    inner join cd.facilities facs
        on bks.facid = facs.facid
where
    facs.name in ('Tennis Court 2','Tennis Court 1')
order by member, facility
```

With that information, I decided to add the *DISTINCT* clause to my solution so it looked like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(mem.firstname || ' ' || mem.surname) AS member, fac.name AS facility
FROM 
    cd.members mem
    INNER JOIN cd.bookings book
        ON mem.memid = book.memid
    INNER JOIN cd.facilities fac
        ON book.facid = fac.facid
WHERE
    fac.facid IN (0,1)
ORDER BY mem.firstname, fac.name
```

However, I got the following error

> ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
> Position: 313

Given that, as you can see, the provided solution is not very different from my second take on the problem except for the last line: while I ask SQL to order by the columns referencing their tables (mem.firstname, fac.name), the solution only references their aliases (member, facility), I have some questions:

1. How is that the *ORDER BY* clause works different when I reference the tables vs when I only use the aliases? I thought that using columns' aliases didn't work on queries as table aliases did.
2. How is the *DISTINCT* clause working in each case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `ORDER BY mem.firstname`, while the solution uses `member`. What is important here is that, `member` not only contains that `firstname`, but actually that exact thing the error message hints at:

`ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list`

Interpretation: When selecting a distinct value, all expressions in your `GROUP BY` must be distinct.

So, the reason for the error, is because you tell it to order by **only** the first name, and that attribute **must** be what you said to be `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` clause. But it isn't, it is *partially there*, but there's also: `' ' || mems.surname`

Comment: Thanks! I tried
`ORDER BY mem.firstname || ' ' || mem.surname, fac.name`
and it worked.

Comment: Right on, OR, because you have: `mem.firstname || ' ' || mem.surname AS member`. You can `GROUP BY member` instead! That's a lot better, as you don't repeat it as much, and after all, why not use `member` when you have created it? Best of luck to you! :)